# Not able to globalize variables from a manipulate expression

Tags: manipulate

I am attempting to globalize the variables inside of a `Manipulate` expression for which my variables are also using interdependent controls. I have attempted to use `LocalizeVariables -> False`, but I am getting errors which I do not fully comprehend as an output. Ultimately I would like to use the variables to evaluate an expression involving other (global) variables. The relevant code is as follows:

```
    Manipulate[
     Show[
      Plot[1, {x, 
        SN (3.89 - Subscript[x, 11] + Subscript[s, 3] - Subscript[t, 3]), 
        SN (3.89 + Subscript[s, 3])}, PlotStyle -> Black],
      Plot[.75, {x, 
        SN (6.42 - Subscript[x, 10] + Subscript[s, 2] - Subscript[t, 2]), 
        SN (6.42 + Subscript[s, 2])}, PlotStyle -> Black],
      Plot[.5, {x, 
        SN (8.07 - Subscript[x, 9] + Subscript[s, 1] - Subscript[t, 1]), 
        SN (8.07 + Subscript[s, 1])}, PlotStyle -> Black],
      Plot[.25, {x, 
        SN (10.67 - Subscript[x, 8] + Subscript[s, 0] - Subscript[t, 0]), 
        SN (10.67 + Subscript[s, 0])}, PlotStyle -> Black], 
      PlotRange -> All,
      Epilog -> {Directive[Black, Dashed],
        Line[{{SN (3.89 - Subscript[x, 11] + Subscript[s, 3] - Subscript[
              t, 3]), 0}, {SN (3.89 - Subscript[x, 11] + Subscript[s, 3] -
               Subscript[t, 3]), 1}}], 
        Line[{{SN (3.89 + Subscript[s, 3]), 
           0}, {SN (3.89 + Subscript[s, 3]), 1}}],
        Line[{{SN (6.42 - Subscript[x, 10] + Subscript[s, 2] - Subscript[
              t, 2]), 
           0}, {SN (6.42 - Subscript[x, 10] + Subscript[s, 2] - Subscript[
              t, 2]), .75}}], 
        Line[{{SN (6.42 + Subscript[s, 2]), 
           0}, {SN (6.42 + Subscript[s, 2]), .75}}],
        Line[{{SN (8.07 - Subscript[x, 9] + Subscript[s, 1] - Subscript[t,
               1]), 0}, {SN (8.07 - Subscript[x, 9] + Subscript[s, 1] - 
              Subscript[t, 1]), .5}}], 
        Line[{{SN (8.07 + Subscript[s, 1]), 
           0}, {SN (8.07 + Subscript[s, 1]), .5}}],
        Line[{{SN (10.67 - Subscript[x, 8] + Subscript[s, 0] - Subscript[
              t, 0]), 0}, {SN (10.67 - Subscript[x, 8] + Subscript[s, 0] -
               Subscript[t, 0]), .25}}], 
        Line[{{SN (10.67 + Subscript[s, 0]), 
           0}, {SN (10.67 + Subscript[s, 0]), .25}}]},
      Axes -> False,
      Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, False}},
      FrameLabel -> {{None, 
         None}, {"Years", 
         None}}
      ] ,
     {{Subscript[s, 0], 0, "Phase 0 Shift"}, -2.0 + Subscript[s, 1], 
      20},
     {{Subscript[t, 0], 0, "{Phase 0 Extend"}, -2.5, 
      10.67 + Subscript[s, 0] - (8.07 + Subscript[s, 1]) + Subscript[t, 
       1]},
     {{Subscript[s, 1], 0, "Phase I Shift"}, -7.92 + 6.42 + Subscript[s, 
       2], (2 + Subscript[s, 0])},
     {{Subscript[t, 1], 0, "Phase I Extend"}, -2.5, 
      8.07 + Subscript[s, 1] - (6.42 + Subscript[s, 2]) + Subscript[t, 2]},
     {{Subscript[s, 2], 0, "Phase II Shift"}, -5.89 + 3.89 + Subscript[s, 
       3], (1.5 + Subscript[s, 1])},
     {{Subscript[t, 2], 0, "Phase II Extend"}, -3, 
      6.55 + Subscript[s, 2] - (3.89 + Subscript[s, 3]) - Subscript[t, 3]},
     {{Subscript[s, 3], 0, "Phase III Shift"}, -1.43 + 
       1.33, (2 + Subscript[s, 2])},
     {{Subscript[t, 3], 0, 
       "Phase III Extend"}, -(3 + Subscript[s, 2] - Subscript[t, 2]), 
      Subscript[s, 3]}
```

Where the following are globally defined variables:

```
SN = 1 or -1
x8 = 2.6
x9 = 2.7
x10 = 3.1
x11 = 3.7
```

This produces the graphs and allows for control over them through the variables S0...S3 and T0...T3. If I set the LocalizeVariables parameter to False, I am hit with several errors. I have also tried fiddling around with dynamic but I keep breaking the code I do have, as I am unfamiliar with that command.

It seems to me like LocalizeVariables is the easiest way to make this work and I'm missing something simple. I have also tried inserting an expression and having the sliders both evaluate the expression and manipulate the plot, but I was unable to figure out how to make this happen either. Could anyone what I'm missing here? I'm very new to the program and am at a loss for where to start.

Thanks